# ExtraTreesClassifier : When trying to pull feature importances, getting a 'NotFittedError' when the model is already fitted

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have fitted ExtraTreeClassifers model using Pipeline

```
etc_final.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here are the model parameters

```
Pipeline(steps=[('scale', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),
                ('clf',
                 OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=ExtraTreesClassifier(criterion='entropy',
                                                                    min_samples_leaf=5,
                                                                    min_samples_split=5,
                                                                    n_estimators=200)))])
```

Next, i try to pull `feature_importances_`

```
etc_final.steps[1][1].estimator.feature_importances_
```

Getting this error

```
NotFittedError: This ExtraTreesClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Can someone help point out what is it that I am doing incorrectly? How can I pull `feature_importances_` when I am using pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

In `OneVsRestClassifier`, the attribute `estimator` is the *unfitted* estimator.  There are several fitted estimators, one for each class, that live in the `estimators_` attribute.  So

```py
[est.feature_importances_ for est in etc_final.steps[1][1].estimators_]
```

will contain the information you want.

Comment: Thanks @Ben .. Somehow not working for my code.. However, i just fit the model ```etc_final[1].estimator.fit(X_train,y_train)``` and then applied this ```feature_importance = etc_final[1].estimator.feature_importances_```. It took care of it